# NEHotspotConfiguration invalid WPA/WPA2 passphrase length

Tags: ios, swift

When I use `NEHotspotConfigurationManager` to join a wpa2 network with 64 hex digits, I got the error:

> NEHotspotConfiguration invalid WPA/WPA2 passphrase length

I got the reason from the documentation:

> for WPA or WPA2 personal networks, 8-63 characters

But is there any solutions to solve it ?

My code:

```
let pwd = "123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890abcd"
let hotspot = NEHotspotConfiguration(ssid: ssid, passphrase: pwd, isWEP: false)
NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.apply(hotspot) { (error) in
    completionHandler?(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to connect with PMK(Pairwise Master Key), but the API requires PSK (pre-shared key, aka wifi password). PMK is computed from network SSID and PSK like this:

```
PMK = PBKDF2-SHA1(PSK, ESSID, 4096)
```

So if the API doesn't accept precomputed PMK, you have to use SSID+PSK to connect.