# Swift NEHotspotConfigurationManager: invalid WEP passphrase length

Tags: swift, nehotspotconfigurationmanager

I'm trying to connect to a WEP wifi network programatically using NEHotspotConfigurationManager. I've enabled the capabilities and using the method below to connect. When attempting to connect however I get the following error:

```
NEHotspotConfigurationErrorDomain Code=3 "invalid WEP Passphrase."
```

I've verified the password is correct and it is being passed to the method below.

```
private func connectWithPassword(params: WifiObject, completion: @escaping (AppError?) -> ()) {
    
    let configuration       =   NEHotspotConfiguration.init(ssid: params.ssid, passphrase: params.passphrase, isWEP: params.isWep)
    configuration.joinOnce  =   true
    configuration.hidden    =   params.hidden
    
    NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.apply(configuration) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            completion(AppError.BadWifi)
        }
        else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I've managed to source this thread below where it mentions encrypting the passphrase before initialising the NEHotspotConfiguration but gives no indication where to encrypt, or that encryption is the right way. Is this something I should be doing and how?

[NEHotspotConfiguration invalid WPA/WPA2 passphrase length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54213518/nehotspotconfiguration-invalid-wpa-wpa2-passphrase-length)

Thanks